# Cakephp3 show syntax error in webserver

Tags: cakephp-3.0

When i put the application in the webserver, i receive that error in log file from app/webroot/error_log but the app works normally in localhost.

```
[14-May-2015 22:51:59] PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected T_STRING, expecting T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING or '(' in /public_html/app/webroot/index.php on line 29
```

Comment: What PHP version are you using? 

HTTP Server. For example: Apache. Having mod_rewrite is preferred, but by no means required.
PHP 5.4.16 or greater.
mbstring extension
intl extension

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this release will not work on php < 5.3.0
Please, update Your server config like PHP Configuration